# There's an issue with my browserSync, it isn't reloading my sass file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm trying to get my gulpfile to watch reload when I change my sass file. Currently I have to close gulp cmd in terminal and refresh for it to work.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

```js
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './app'
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using the Gulp 4. Used this code:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) //removed semicolon
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

// watch Sass files for changes, run the Sass preprocessor with the 'sass' task and reload
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('styles', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: './app'
    }
  });

  gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

If you using old Gulp:

```
let gulp = require("gulp");
let sass = require("gulp-sass");
let browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
let runSequence = require('run-sequence'); // npm install run-sequence --save-dev

gulp.task("styles", function () {
    gulp
      .src("app/scss/*.scss")
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

// Static server
gulp.task("serve", function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});


//watch for files changes
gulp.task('watch', ['styles', 'serve'], function () {
    // sass files changes
    gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);

    // CSS files changes
    gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', browserSync.reload);

    // html files changes
    ulp.watch('app/**/*.html', browserSync.reload)
});

// The default task (called when you run 'gulp' from cli)
gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
    runSequence(['styles', 'serve', 'watch'],
      callback
    )
})
```